# How to set a specific textview to have focuse on start, and how to always display the contents of the textviews?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, focus, visibility

I have a small program with two textviews, when app starts the second is focused (i want the first one) and whenever I input something into them and then focuses something else, the input data will not be displayed - the textview will be blank but it doesnt really disappear because you can hover over it to see it again.

How do I set these things?

/// This is my main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/artisttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Artist.." 
        android:hint="Artist..">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/tracktext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Track.."
        android:hint="Track.."> >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/artistEnter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get similar artists" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/songEnter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get similar tracks" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to set focus, but not the issue of when chnging focus from one tetview to the other, the one that lost focus also sets is text to invisible til it get focused again. Why is this?

Comment: Solution: AutoCompleteTextViews have automatically generated <requestFocus/> which you can just remove or add to suit ur ideas. Also, the tet vanishing is solved by dding this to the .xml:  android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light">